# Absolutely position one element relative to its sibling element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, position, absolute

I have this kind of situation. I am using Navigation bar wrapper that when clicked pull out an overlay across whole page. 
For this to work all the elements that overlay goes across are sibling elements. One of those siblings is Header, Body, Footer...
I need to position navigation bar absolutely on top of Header element, so it doesn’t go out of boundaries of Header. If I put position absolute on Navigation bar it positions it relative to whole page since there is no parent element with position relative above it. If I put position relative on Header it doesn't help since it a sibling and not parent of Navigation bar.

Is it possible to absolutely position one element relative to its sibling element?

EDIT: Don't know how much code will help since it's a pretty big application and I bolied the question down to simple terms.

**Scenes**

```
const Scenes = (props: Props) => (
  <NavigationWrapper routes={props.routes}>
    <Header />
    {renderRoutes(props.routes)}
  </NavigationWrapper>
)
```

**NavigationWrapper**

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component, Fragment, } from 'react'
import { NavLink, } from 'react-router-dom'
import Icon from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Icon/Icon'
import Image from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Image/Image'
import Menu from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/collections/Menu/Menu'
import Sidebar from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/modules/Sidebar/Sidebar'
import Responsive from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/addons/Responsive/Responsive'
// Flow
import type { Element, } from 'react'

import logo from '../../../assets/img/logo.png'

import './navigationWrapper.local.scss'

const NavBarMobile = ({
  children, onPusherClick, onToggle, rightItems, visible,
}) => (
  <Sidebar.Pushable>
    <Sidebar
      as={Menu}
      animation="overlay"
      icon="labeled"
      items={rightItems}
      vertical
      visible={visible}
    >
      <Menu.Item>
        <Image size="mini" src={logo} />
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Menu>{rightItems.map(item => <Menu.Item as={NavLink} {...item} exact />)}</Menu.Menu>
    </Sidebar>
    <Sidebar.Pusher dimmed={visible} onClick={onPusherClick} style={{ minHeight: '100vh', }}>
      <Menu fixed="top" inverted>
        <Menu.Item onClick={onToggle} position="right">
          <Icon name="sidebar" />
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
      {children}
    </Sidebar.Pusher>
  </Sidebar.Pushable>
)

const NavBarDesktop = ({ rightItems, }) => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
      <Image size="mini" src={logo} />
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Menu position="right">
      {rightItems.map(item => <Menu.Item as={NavLink} {...item} exact />)}
    </Menu.Menu>
  </Menu>
)

const NavBarChildren = ({ children, }) => children

type State = {
  visible: boolean,
}

type Props = {
  children: Object,
}

class NavigationWrapper extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    visible: false,
  }

  handlePusher = () => {
    const { visible, } = this.state

    if (visible) this.setState({ visible: false, })
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, })

  render(): Element<any> {
    const rightItems = [
      {
        to: '/',
        content: 'Kuci',
        key: 'home',
      },
      {
        to: '/o-nama',
        content: 'O Nama',
        key: 'aboutus',
      },
      {
        to: '/usluge',
        content: 'Usluge',
        key: 'services',
      },
      {
        to: '/kontakti',
        content: 'Kontakti',
        key: 'contacts',
      },
    ]

    const { children, } = this.props
    const { visible, } = this.state

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Responsive {...Responsive.onlyMobile}>
          <NavBarMobile
            onPusherClick={this.handlePusher}
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            rightItems={rightItems}
            visible={visible}
          >
            <NavBarChildren>{children}</NavBarChildren>
          </NavBarMobile>
        </Responsive>
        <Responsive minWidth={Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth}>
          <NavBarDesktop rightItems={rightItems} />
          <NavBarChildren>{children}</NavBarChildren>
        </Responsive>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default NavigationWrapper
```

I am passing everything inside NavigationWrapper and render it as a children. It looks like this inside of DOM. As you can see in the console, **ui menu** is navigation bar, **container__header** is cover image. They are all siblings. I need to position **ui menu** relative to **container__header**, for example put it in the middle, but if I put for example bottom: 0, it must not go out of **container__header**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an example of your code, it's difficult to assist; however, it sounds like you want to use `position: fixed` as opposed to `position: absolute`.

Comment: I added example. Position fixed will fix it to entier page and I want to just  position it inside header.

Comment: So if I am following correctly, you want the nav bar to be centered within the header only?

Comment: Yes. Centered, or like 30% down.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't place the nav component inside the header and then position absolutely within that container?

Comment: Hi ekfuhrmann, thank for the example. Unfortunately, no, if I could that would make my life much easier, but the application is pretty big and structured that that way. Semantic UI React also does this automatically when passing data and there would be server side rendering problems involved if I were to change it along with some additional stuff that I am probably not even aware off.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk In that case you could use JS to calculate the height of the header and nav and then calculate it to the position you want.

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/ekfuhrmann/pen/OZYPOv?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to get the sibling-elements position after the page has completely loaded, then use jquery to set the CSS of your element to the exact position in which it needs to be. -another trick is to open Developer Tools in your browser and just look for the CSS section, and change it to each possible option for position and see if any of them or a combination of CSS attributes work for you. It's very easy in FireFox.

Comment: I am not using jQuery, made a lot of effort to cut it entirely out from application.

Comment: Why? 11 more characters

Comment: It's a bad mix to use React and jQuery together. Also it's a pretty big library.